# Each week add one blank column

Tags: php

How to add blank column for each WEEK like demonstrated in this image:
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/758229excel.png

I have this code:

```
while($j < $tout - 1) {
   echo $j." -> ".($j+6)."<br>";
   $excel2->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("A".$j.":A".($j+6))
                     ->setCellValue("A".$j, $o);   
   $j += 7; 
   $o++;                 
}
```

This generate numbers like this:

```
9 -> 15
16 -> 22
23 -> 29
30 -> 36
37 -> 43
44 -> 50
51 -> 57
58 -> 64
65 -> 71
72 -> 78
...
```

I want for each week i add +1 to get blank column.

For example, when i arrive to 44 -> 50 the next will be:

```
52 -> 58
...
```

Hope you understand me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$i=0;
while($j < $tout - 1)
{
   $i++;
   if($i > 6) {
        $j += 1;
        $i = 0;
   }
   echo $j." -> ".($j+6)."<br>";
   $excel2->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("A".$j.":A".($j+6))
                     ->setCellValue("A".$j, $o);   
   $j += 7; 
   $o++;
}
```

Hope this will work...

Comment: Work like a charm, thank you a lot :) it's what i need !

Comment: Accepted, sorry for the time, i am new here ;)

Comment: How to do the same with this ?  for($u = 0; $u < $tout - 1; $u++)
{     

       
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$i, ($i - 1))
                         ->setCellValue('C'.$i, en_francais(date('D', strtotime($dates[$u]))))
       ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $dates[$u]);
              
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$i)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$i)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$i++;
}

Comment: Just same as my answer, Difference is only loop...
`
for($u = 0; $u < $tout - 1; $u++) {
   $i++;
   if($i > 6) {
        $u += 1;
        $i = 0;
   }
}
`

Comment: i tried but no result, must know that i defined those like this: $i = 2;
$j = 9;
$o = 2; but when i tried your code i get only 5 columns of dates , originaly have 140 ($tout - 1) :)

Comment: hey wait...
use another variable instead of my variable `$i`...
I have seen you used $i in `setCellValue`, so change my variable to another...

Answer (score 0):

You could add 1 more counter variable (ie. `$x`), and increase by 8 -

```
$x = $j; // initiate to start with $j
while($j < $tout - 1) {
   echo $j." -> ".($j+6)."<br>";
   echo "<br>"; // mimics $x in excel below
   $excel2->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("A".$x.":A".($x+6))
                     ->setCellValue("A".$x, $o);   
   $j += 7; 
   $x += 8; // creates 1 blank after $j
   $o++;                 
}
```